# How to completely remove mokutil as purge didn't do the trick?

Tags: boot

`sudo apt purge mokutil` Yet when I login I still get the settings screen.

How does one remove this? I did initially create a key, do I need to delete it to remove the screen? But since the program is purged, the boot screen shouldn't exist anymore.

Version: `0.3.0+1538710437.fb6250f-0ubuntu2~16.04.1`

Comment: What is your goal? You won't remove keys or anything of that kind by removing mokutil. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy mokutil` and `which mokutil` to the question.

Comment: Goal is just to completely remove every possible inkling of mokutil. Don't want it to show up on boot.